# accepts_nested_attributes_for with key "_destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, destroy

The situation:

```
class Cellar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :house, allow_destroy: true

  attr_accessible :house_id, :house_attributes, [...]
end
```

.

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one: cellar
end
```

The problem:

When I send the `Cellar` form and include the key-value pair `"_destroy" => "true"` inside the `house_attributes`, the House gets destroyed as it should, but the `Cellar.house_id` is not updated to NULL.

Is this normal behavior? How should I best fix this?

Comment: You have confounding declarations in your models. Your `Cellar` model is set to `dependent: :destroy` on the parent `House` object, yet you want the `Cellar` object to remain after the house is destroyed? This doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: Even if I comment out ```dependent: :destroy```, the problem stays the same.

Comment: Your association is fundamentally flawed. The parent should accept nested attributes for the child - not the other way around.

Comment: I know it's a "reverse case", but it my situation this was necessary - and perfectly working, except for this issue...

Comment: In that case, it's not working perfectly. I would suggest you rework your `House` model such that it nullifies the `house_id` attribute on the child `Cellar` object on destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's what I ended up doing in order to correct the issue:

```
class Cellar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :house, allow_destroy: true

  attr_accessible :house_id, :house_attributes, [...]

  # I ADDED THIS:
  before_save :drop_invalid_id
  def drop_invalid_id
    self.house_id = nil if house.marked_for_destruction?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be normal depending on the version of Rails... I think up until Rails 3.2 it was normal for the foreign key to remain untouched when destroying object (and vice versa when updating a foreign key to nil). What version of Rails are you using?

But, regardless, if you want to keep going as is and just clean up the foreign key on `@cellar` after saving then you can always just call `@cellar.reload` after the successful `@cellar.save`. This would refresh the state of your `@cellar` object from the database and remove the `house_id` attribute since it's no longer present.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.12. But unfortunately, ```@cellar.reload``` does not remove the ```house_id``` (which was submitted alongside the ```house_attributes``` and the ```_destroy``` key) from the db. So I guess I'm left with the 3 choices: a) zeantsoi's suggestion (rework the Model), or b) remove the ```id``` from the form using JS, or c) delete it from the db, after the save.

Comment: Oops, b) does obviously not make sense.